# Django Raw SQL Query - How to pull value via column (instead of tuple index) from SELECT query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm executing a `fetchall()` ***raw SQL query*** in Django (1.11) with a `PostgreSQL` data source. The result returns a `tuple`.

My concern is that I can only seem to fetch a row's field via the tuple index i.e. `row[2]` (or in template I would do `{{row.2}}`). But I want to be able to use the ***actual field name*** instead of index i.e. `row.itemno` (or in template I would do `{{row.itemno}}`)

I tried doing row.first_name but it says *`'list' object has no attribute 'itemno'`*

Is it or isn't it possible to use field names with this result?

Here's a sample in python shell:

[image]

P.S. You might be wondering why I'm still using Django 1.11... It's because we are using DjangoCMS and unfortunately, it supports up to 1.11 only...

Comment: You could create a namedtuple to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

django documentation explains how you can [execute custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly). From the Docs:

> By default, the Python DB API will return results without their field names, which means you end up with a list of values, rather than a dict. At a small performance and memory cost, you can return results as a dict by using something like this:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Or you can you namedtuple as well.

```
from collections import namedtuple

def namedtuplefetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a namedtuple"
    desc = cursor.description
    nt_result = namedtuple('Result', [col[0] for col in desc])
    return [nt_result(*row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I considered the suggestions to use `namedtuple`.

It's giving me what I want so far; I can now do something like `{{row.field}}` in my template.

But I think I need to make sure that my process isn't too complicated and tiresome. Maybe just a little more help to evaluate my code below if it's already ideal or not?

[image]